# background-position is removed on page load

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a HTML page that tries to display some icons from a sprite image.
I added the css file, and also put the sprite image in the current working directory. For reference, one of the icon has the definition like as shown below,

```
.locicon{
        background-position: -61px -110px ;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: url(htsprite1.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

**Problem:** However, when the page is loaded, the icons are not getting displayed.
When inspecting on chrome and firefox, I can see the sprite image, and this is the runtime definition of the class `locicon` :

```
.locicon{
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: url(htsprite1.png) no-repeat;
        }
```

Everything except the  `background-position`. Why is it happening like this?
I checked if this property is overriden somewhere and couldn't find any such instance while inspecting on the element.

Note: Before  posting here, I even tried with a plain HTML file , including the css file, and tested, still the same issue .
`background-position` is getting removed at runtime!

Note: The Sprite wont appear in my case even after resolving this because of this linked issue, which is rectified now : Just for reference: [CSS sprite not appearing in Firefox, but displaying in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148190/css-sprite-not-appearing-in-firefox-but-displaying-in-chrome)

Comment: Because you are using 'background' shorthand property and same time you are using 'backgroun-position'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `background-position` is overwritten by `background`. Try to set the `background-position`afterwards:

```
background: url(htsprite1.png) no-repeat;
background-position: -61px -110px;
```

A cleaner solution would be to set the background properties separately:

```
background-image: url(htsprite1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -61px -110px;
```

Comment: The first approach results in `background: url("htsprite1.png") no-repeat scroll -61px -110px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` , while the second approach looks more cleaner. Thanks, one of my issue was that it was overriden due to the wrong sequence i was using. +1. However still I have issue in displaying the icon. I created the css sprite with the help of this tool - `http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/`

Comment: Can you create a plunker of this?

Comment: sure, let me try that

Comment: Hey @Reto Aebersold , I tried my code on plunker, and it worked, So somewhere else I am messing up, but that's a positive sign for me to move on. Thank you! I'll mark as answer as the initial problem was related to overriding background. Thanks once again, have a good day

Comment: Hi, can you please check this SO question. I Still have issue with the sprites not appearing in Firefox - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147690/background-position-is-removed-on-page-load/30147717#30147717