# CSS sprite not appearing in Firefox, but displaying in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, css-sprites

I am struggling to make a CSS sprite appear in my HTML page, and I couldn't.
Then I put the code on plunker to share the code to SO, and it worked!
Then I understood that it doesn't work on Firefox, but works on Chrome.

Please help me

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.outdoor {
    background-image: url(sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -14px -110px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.parking{
    background-image: url(sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -15px -60px ;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Sprites.. Why are you appearing in Chrome, but not in Firefox? Please appear</h1>
    <img class="outdoor" /><img class="parking" />

</body>

</html>
```

Linked to : [background-position is removed on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147690/background-position-is-removed-on-page-load/30147717#30147717)

*Note: I'm removing the Test URL. The code is present here, and hence doesn't reduce the clarity of the question.*

Comment: Replace <img> with <div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `img` tags with `background-image`. I honestly don't know what browser support is for that, but it's a bad idea. Instead use divs. You'll also need to make the styles forcing it to inline block. Alternatively, you could go with something like font awesome/glyphicon's strategy of `::before` styling, usually used with spans.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.outdoor {
    background-image: url(sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -14px -110px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.parking{
    background-image: url(sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -15px -60px ;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Sprites.. Why are you appearing in Chrome, but not in Firefox? Please appear</h1>
    <div class="outdoor" ></div>
    <div class="parking" ></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `<i>` tag instead of `<div>` tag. as `div` is a block level element.

Its a best practices to use `<i>` tag for image sprite.
Here is the post why `<i>` for icons
[Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .bg_icon{
        background-image: url(sprites.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display:inline-block;
  }
.outdoor {
    background-position: -14px -110px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.parking{
    background-position: -15px -60px ;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Sprites.. Why are you appearing in Chrome, but not in Firefox? Please appear</h1>
    <i class="bg_icon outdoor" ></i>
    <i class="bg_icon parking" ></i>

</body>

</html>
```